# Преобразование строки в массив с извлечением цифр Javascript

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста разобраться!)

Написать функцию, которая примет строку, содержащую:

- буквы,
- целые неотрицательные числа
- и иные символы.

Требуется все числа, которые встречаются в строке, поместить в отдельный целочисленный массив. Функция должна возвращать этот массив.

Например: "djhf5 gf44 h00dbsh198".
При том что регулярные выражения нельзя использовать.
Должно возвращать массив чисел [123,6,0,0,6,90]

Вот мой код

```
let nums = 'asdf123 d6 lkj006m90';
let numOfarray = function(inputArray){
    let array = inputArray.split(' ');
    console.log(array);
    array = Number.isNaN(Number(array));
}
numOfarray(nums);
```

Comment: Вы пытались сами реализовать данную функцию? Можно узнать с какими именно сложностями столкнулись? Можно увидеть код попытки вашей реализации?

Comment: let nums = 'asdf123 d6 lkj006m90';
let numOfarray = function(inputArray){
    let array = inputArray.split(' ');
    console.log(array);
   array = Number.isNaN(Number(array));
}
 numOfarray(nums)

Comment: Функция должна возвращать именно массив чисел или массив цифр

Comment: допишите в вопросе ожидаемый результат

Comment: @the_Solomon, Должен выводится массив чисел [123,6,0,0,6,90]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const numOfString = (string) => {
  const numbs = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    const symbol = parseInt(string[i]);
    if(!isNaN(symbol)){
      numbs.push(symbol);
    }
  }

  return numbs;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @SaNFeeD- спасибо огромное)))

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему этот ответ отмечен решением. Строка "asdf123 d6 lkj006m90" должна превратиться в [123,6,0,0,6,90],  а у вас будет [1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0, 6, 9, 0]

Comment: @the_Solomon, человек получил что хотел и отметил ответ как решенный. В чем вопрос?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, хорошо. Впредь буду давать более развернутый ответ.

Comment: отмечено как решенное, потому что мной не было указано изначально уточнения, каков должен получится результат. По тому как поступил вопрос о нужном ответе при выходе, то я решил его написать.